# Subversion Author name in source file

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

After switching from Eclipse Indigo(Old SVN) to luna, i updated SVN plugin to 2.0.1. Now i am not getting the author name who are committed to revision and time of commit in latest SVN 2.0.1 for Eclipse Luna.

1. **Luna**

[image: SVN Updated Snapshot]

2. **Indigo**

[image: Old SVN Snapshot]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> Label Decorations -> "Text Decorations" tab -> add `{date} {author}` into "File", "Folder" or "Project" format.